# Trying to create a custom process that shares specific information

Tags: google-sheets

I work for a high school that has a regular four day school week and calls students in for "Reteach and Enrichment" on Fridays. To help organize the schedule for this, the school has created a Google Sheet that lists all of the student names and allows the teachers to fill in what time they would like any particular student to come to their class that Friday. This is working fine for the school's organizational side, but informing students of their assignments is currently a bit of a nightmare.

Because students will try to get out of anything, we have to have documentation indicating that we "told the students they need to come to our classroom on Friday". This is currently done in the form of giving a student a slip of carbon copy paper informing them of the time they are called in. As you can imagine, this is extremely time-consuming and full of holes since the students can throw the paper away or claim "they never got the paper" even though we've got a second copy of that paper indicating that it was filled out. But I digress.

The reason I'm writing to you fellow internet people is that I've taken on the task of trying to streamline the process of notifying the students of their schedules for Fridays. Because of privacy issues, we cannot give the students read-only access to the master list for Fridays, but I'm looking for a way to inform them of their specific information. My first thought was to write a program that would make a google sheet of each line on the master sheet, and share that sheet with the student whose information was on that line. This seems painful to set up and manage though and will lead to a lot of documents in google drives that are only needed for a week. The second problem is that I'm not sure what type of application I could use to run a program that would need to be able to access one google sheet, copy information from it, create a new google sheet, paste the copied information, gather the correct account the information needs to be shared with, and share read access to the new sheet that was created. I was thinking of using Auto Hotkey, but I know there's got to be a better solution to this problem.

If you have any suggestions for a different approach, please let me know. I believe that I can get an automated process to do what I described above if I can get the process down to a rote set of steps to take for each line on the original google sheet. But I'm hoping there's a way to do like an XLookup or Vlookup from a new sheet that references the original or something.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131312/186471

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You could either use Google Sheets formulas or [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). What do you **exactly** want to achieve? To get the info from the students into their own sheet? If you could provide a sample sheet *with no sensitive data* of what you have and what your desired output is it would be easier for us to fully understand your context. Thanks ! :D